# Singleton ou classe e membros estaticos?

Tags: design-pattern

Estava pesquisando alguns projetos em *.Net* e *Java* e pelo que entendi dos benefícios do *Singleton*, achei desnecessário a utilização do mesmo. **Por exemplo:** em um projeto o mesmo era utilizado para instanciar classes que faziam o carregamento de dados na memoria quando o programa era iniciado. Nesse caso, porque não chamar um método estático onde carregue todos esses dados na memoria?

Quais são as vantagens de utilizar o designe pattern *Singleton*?

**Não consigo pensar em nenhum exemplo onde não seja possível substituir qualquer implementação *Singleton* por um simples uso de *membros estáticos*.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Desfazendo uma confusão

> em um projeto o [padrão Singleton] era utilizado para instanciar classes que faziam o carregamento de dados na memoria quando o programa era iniciado.

Na verdade, o Singleton **não** serve para iniciar dados no início do programa, mas sim para garantir uma instância única (dentro de um contexto) de um certo objeto.

Aí, não importa se o objeto é instanciado no início do programa (*eager*) ou na primeira chamado ao método (*lazy*).

## Duas implementações

```java
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton eagerInstance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton getEagerInstance() {
        return eagerInstance;
    }

    private static Singleton lazyInstance;
    public static Singleton getLazyInstance() {
        if (lazyInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (lazyInstance == null) {
                    lazyInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return lazyInstance;
    }

}
```

Instanciar o objeto no início do programa (ou no carregamento da classe) é mais simples, porque não precisamos nos preocupar com sincronização. Porém, os recursos usados são alocados mesmo que não venham a ser usados.

Deixa para instanciar o objeto sob demanda economiza recursos em alguns casos, mas pode causar um certo atraso na resposta ao primeiro cliente que use o recurso e exige cuidados extras com a concorrência. Sim, os dois `if`s são necessários para garantir 100% que não há chance de carregar o objeto duas vezes numa chamada concorrente.

## To Singleton or not to Singleton?

Agora, pense no exemplo *eager* e no seguinte comentário:

> porque não chamar um método estático onde carregue todos esses dados na memoria?

Carregar os dados em memória através de um método estático é praticamente o que fiz no exemplo acima. Então, no fim das contas, sua implementação ainda é um Singleton.

Por outro lado, se você acessa as instâncias diretamente por um atributo, por exemplo `Singleton.instance`, então realmente não se trata do padrão Singleton.

E isso traz várias desvantagens, que vão além das desvantagens do próprio padrão Singleton, como a quebra de encapsulamento e o alto acoplamento entre implementações.

## Considerações

Em última análise, todo padrão de projeto é dispensável.

Quem leu o GoF com atenção já deve ter percebido que o efeito colateral mais citado nos padrões é o aumento da complexidade e do número de classes.

A verdade é que existem formas muito mais diretas de resolver os problemas. A grande diferença entre não usar padrões e usá-los (adequadamente) pode ser observada a longo prazo.

Resolver um problema de forma mais simples e direta pode causar um problema ainda maior do ponto de vista de manutenção. Por exemplo, usar um atributo estático como mencionei acima pode causar sérios problemas se a forma como o sistema funciona mudar. Imagine se amanhã ele não for mais um Singleton, mas precisar ser um `ThreadLocal` (Singleton por thread). Podem também emergir erros graves após testes de carga, desempenho e concorrência que exijam sincronização do objeto recuperado.

Por fim, vamos considerar a última afirmação:

> Não consigo pensar em nenhum exemplo onde não seja possível substituir qualquer implementação Singleton por um simples uso de membros estáticos.

Em geral, isso ocorre porque não há diferença. O padrão Singleton é apenas uma formalização de como acessar devidamente um atributo estático.

Comment: Ótima resposta! A última frase sanou minha dúvida. Meu erro foi levar o padrão singleton como uma regra, tipo "eu preciso implementa-lo em algum lugar do meu código!".

Answer (score 3):

A aplicação para ele são várias, o que você citou é mais um exemplo de implementação, entretanto o real objetivo de ter um *singleton* é garantir que ela só será instanciada uma vez, aqui vai um exemplo prático:

Imagine a seguinte situação, o ponteiro do mouse é uma classe do tipo *singleton* e só poderá ser instanciado apenas uma vez.

Comment: Mas o que não consigo entender é porque não apenas utilizar como estático já que vai ter apenas uma instância. Na minha cabeça é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Não, o método estático é para usar sem uma instância do objeto assim como uma *classe estática* você pode usar várias vezes o método/objeto estático, uma *classe singleton* não.

Answer (score 3):

Gustavo Piucco, o padrão de projeto singleton existe para garantir que uma determinada classe será instanciada apenas uma vez. Ele é comumente utilizado com uma fachada, para garantir que uma aplicação desenvolvida em N Camadas tenha apenas um ponto de entrada. Segue abaixo um exemplo prático do mesmo. Neste exemplo, temos uma classe Fachada que acessa diretamente suas classes de negócio. Para garantir que não exista mais de uma instância acessando estas classes de negócio, utiliza-se o singleton.

```
public class Fachada
{
    private Fachada instancia;  

    private Fachada()
    {
    }

    public static Fachada GetFachada()
    {
        if(instancia == null)
            instancia = new Fachada();
        return instancia;
    }   

    //Métodos de acesso a classe de negócio

}
```

Diferentemente de uma classe static, o singleton permite que você tenha métodos e objetos não estáticos.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando Singleton **ao contrário** de uma classe estática, sua classe dependendo do cenário pode:

- Herdar de uma outra classe
- Ser herdada;
- Implementar uma interface;
- Ser serializada;
- Ser passada para outras classes;
- Ser testada de forma mais fácil;

Utilizando a [classe estática](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) teria apenas métodos estáticos.

Answer (score 2):

A vantagem de se usar o Singleton é que o código que acessa o Singleton não conhece como o mesmo foi implementando. Veja o exemplo do singleton abaixo, em Java:

```
public class MySingleton {
      // Variavel estática que conterá a instancia do método
      private static MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

     static {
              // Operações de inicialização da classe
     }

     // Construtor privado. Suprime o construtor público padrao.
     private MySingleton() {
     }

     // Método público estático de acesso único ao objeto!
     public static MySingleton getInstance(){

           // O valor é retornado para quem está pedindo
           return INSTANCE;
     }
 }
```

O código que chama o Singleton simplesmente executa: `MySingleton.getInstance();`, não sabendo se o mesmo é uma instância estática ou se um objeto é criado a cada momento que essa chamada é feita. O interessante dessa abordagem é que o cliente, ou seja, quem chama o Singleton, não está interessado em conhecer a implementação do Singleton, ou seja do serviço que ele chama.

A vantagem de se utilizar o Singleton é a organização do código, utilizando-se encapsulamento. Perceba que utilizando-se simplesmente chamadas estáticas de métodos, tal boa prática não é aplicada.

Um exemplo clássico o caso de log, onde se deseja apenas uma instância em toda a aplicação gerando log, já que o mesmo é feito em apenas um arquivo.

Veja o [link da wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) com explicações de Sigleton.

Comment: A vantagem de se usar o Singleton não é que o código que acessa o Singleton não conhece como o mesmo foi implementando. @EduardoFernandes Penso que isso é encapsulamento, um princípio importante da orientação a objeto, mas não se trata de uma "vantagem" de utilização do Singleton.

Comment: Você está certo :). Obrigado

Comment: Sim, de fato ocorre encapsulamento com o Singleton. Porém é possível você encapsular métodos, organizar seu código, usar recursos p/ diminuir acoplamento entre objetos, etc., sem usar Singleton.

Comment: Concordo, mas a ideia aqui é mostrar vantagens do Singleton.