# Como armazenar dados na memória RAM e fazer com que eles ficam disponiveis para qualquer módulo ou classe da minha aplicação?

Tags: java, memória, estrutura-de-dados

Existe várias formas de armazenar os dados de uma determinada aplicação e algumas delas são:

- Armazenamento em Disco (HD). Pode ser um arquivo de texto, XML, ou um
  arquivo de base de dados de algum SGBD.
- Armazenamento em Nuvem (Cloud). Tem alguns serviços que permite
  armazenar os dados de uma aplicação em Nuvem, o [Google Cloud
  Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) é um deles.
- Armazenamento em Memória RAM. Neste caso os dados se apagariam quando o computador reiniciasse.

Considerando a *memória RAM* entre as formas de armazenamento acima é possível utilizar a *memória RAM* para guardar os dados de forma temporária. Vamos considerar o seguinte exemplo para ilustração:

```
package pesquisalinearvetor;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Dener
 */
public class PesquisaLinearVetor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vetor[] = {1, 33, 21, 2, 4};
        int valor;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Informe o valor para ser pesquisado no vetor: ");
        valor = in.nextInt();
        
        if (pesquisaLinear(valor, vetor))
            System.out.println("Existe o valor " + valor + " no vetor.");
        else
            System.out.println("Não existe o valor " + valor + " no vetor.");                      
    }
    
    private static boolean pesquisaLinear(int valor, int vetorAlvo[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vetorAlvo.length; i++) 
            if (vetorAlvo[i] == valor)
                return true;        
        return false;
    }
}
```

O exemplo acima armazena em memória os valores da variável `vetor` para que possa ser efetuada uma pesquisa linear nela.

## Minha dúvida.

Visto que o acesso as variáveis só e permitido dentro do escopo onde ela foi definida eu gostaria de saber como eu posso armazenar os dados na *memória RAM* e permitir que esses dados estejam acessíveis a partir de qualquer modulo ou classe da minha aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem algumas formas. Cada uma com suas vantagens e desvantagens. Em todas se o uso permitir concorrência terá que controlar o acesso simultâneo preocupando-se que não tenha uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), por exemplo. Vou considerar apenas o acesso *monothread* que não exige maiores preocupações.

O jeito mais simples é criar uma variável estática. Toda variável estática tem tempo de vida igual ao da aplicação e se tiver visibilidade pública poderá ser acessada por qualquer classe.

Entenda que tem uma questão de [escopo e de tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

As variáveis de instância tem tempo de vida igual ao da própria instância. As estáticas vivem por toda aplicação.

As variáveis de instância tem escopo da instância (objeto), portanto são acessadas através dela (ela precisa estar viva e disponível no escopo específico), já as variáveis de classe (estáticas) tem escopo de classe e acessadas através dela, que por sua vez estão sempre em escopo na aplicação.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Acho que fica claro que nenhuma variável pode ser acessada de forma direta. O escopo delas em si sempre está encapsulado em uma estrutura (classe ou instância).

## Caso específico

Não sei bem qual é a necessidade e se esse é apenas um exemplo. Há casos que seria bom ter uma classe só para esse objetivo, talvez com mecanismos que ajudem acessar o dado de forma mais organizada, talvez uma classe genérica permitindo armazenar dados arbitrários conforme a demanda da aplicação.

Nesse caso específico me parece que a forma mais simples é só declarar `vetor` como campo estático da classe (deixa de ser uma variável local do método) e já resolverá o problema de forma simples:

```
public static int vetor;
```

Isso pode ser acessado de qualquer lugar como:

```
PesquisaLinearVetor.vetor
```

Obviamente deixei sem qualquer inicialização no exemplo acima, pode ser que deseje ter um valor já de cara. Lembrando que se tentar acessar esse vetor assim o valor inicial dele será nulo. Se a intenção é ter alguma coisa basta inicializá-lo ali mesmo.

Se houver qualquer razão para não permitir que o dado seja alterado basta colocar como `final`. Mas aí obrigaria inicializar a variável, caso contrário não faz sentido.

## Classe global

```
public final class Global {
    private Global() {} // só pra garantir que não haja instâncias dela
    private static int[] vetor;
    public static int[] getVetor() { return vetor; }
    public static void setVetor(int[] vetor) { this.vetor = vetor; }
    //aqui pode colocar vários outros dados se eles forem relacionados
    //o ideal é criar classe globais para cada necessidade
    //nem sempre é necessário usar getter e setter, o campo público pode ser suficiente
    //é possível criar outras operações específicas de acordo com a necessidade
    //por exemplo pode pegar e setar um elemento do vetor
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Global.java).

Nesse caso é só usar sempre `Global.getVetor() e fazer o que quiser` e `Global.setVetor(um vetor de int aqui)`.

Eu diria que a solução mais simples que é deixar um campo estático na classe que já está usando é mais adequada na maioria dos casos. Se já tem um bom lugar para colocar um dado, pra que criar outro?

## Singleton

Por outro lado manter um acesso global aberto dessa forma pode não ser o mais adequado.

Algumas pessoas preferem, por algumas razões, ter uma classe Singleton do que uma estática pura. Pode ser feito também, tem a limitação que sempre precisa "instanciar" a classe para usar o valor, mas o dado será global do mesmo jeito.

Algumas considerações sobre Singleton e o estado global como um todo:

- [Como aplicar o padrão Singleton corretamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56010/101)
- [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101)
- [Quais problemas um estado global pode acarretar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101)
- [Singleton ou classe e membros estaticos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25306/101)

## HashMap

Essa é uma opção mais genérica que permite segurar vários dados globais de forma facilitada e dinâmica.

```
public class DataHolder {
    private static Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> data = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>();
    public static void save(String id, Object object) {
        data.put(id, new WeakReference<Object>(object));
    }
    public static Object retrieve(String id) {
        WeakReference<Object> objectWeakReference = data.get(id);
        return objectWeakReference.get();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/HashMap.java).

Evidentemente isso pode ser melhorado de acordo com a necessidade. No fundo o mecanismo é sempre o mesmo - há uma variável estática guardando o valor, aqui só foi adicionado um mecanismo extra para generalizar para o caso do problema exigir vários dados globais sob demanda (o que não parece ser o caso da pergunta).

## Banco de dados *in-memory*

Dependendo da necessidade é possível usar um banco de dados mesmo. Alguns trabalham exclusivamente na memória e não precisam de instalação, [é o caso do SQLite](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: Também e possível alterar o conteúdo da variável?

Comment: Sim, pode, desde que não seja `final`.

Comment: Global.gerVetor funciona mesmo não sendo um método estático?

Comment: Oops. Agora está ok.